# How to turn an HList of Const functors into a Seq?

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, higher-kinded-types

I have a higher-kinded data type like this

```
case class Foo[F[_] : Functor](a: F[Int], b: F[Double])
```

and a value that labels every member with some kind of string (the name of a CSV column for example):

```
val colNames = new Foo[Const[String, *]](a = Const("AAA"), b = Const("BBB"))
```

Now I need to somehow convert `colNames` into a `Seq[String]`. There is the standard scala method `productIterator` of course, but it only returns `Iterator[Any]`.

Using shapeless I can get an HList where every type in the list is `Const[String, _]`:

```
val colNamesHlist: Const[String, _] :: Const[String, _] :: HNil = Generic[Foo[Const[String, *]]].to(colNames)
```

But how can I turn this into a regular list?

I am also open to any ideas not involving shapeless, though I don't think it can be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do this:

```scala
val colNameList: List[String] =
  Generic[Foo[Const[String, *]]]
    .to(colNames)
    .toList[Const[String, A] forSome { type A }]
    .map(_.getConst)
```

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/icvSSZ7CRYmdme47nTvKdA/3).

Comment: Thanks, how did I miss that method?